# Does apache have some sort of cache for virtual host configuration?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am trying to simply change my ServerName and Server alias but it will not make the change effective even after restarting apache. Is there some sort of cache that I need to clear somewhere to get the change in my virtual host settings to work?

Comment: Are you changing sites-enabled and not just sites-available?

Comment: This is set up on centos so all the configuration is done in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Paste your vhost config in its entirety.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If it's not working, odds are high that your configuration is incorrect.

Comment: The reason I suspected there was some sort of caching is because I have been running this site fine with a domain name for a while. Just went in to my httpd.conf and changed the domain name and nothing else. The original domain name still works, the new one doesn't.

Comment: And what error do you get when you try to access the site with this new domain?  Do you see the attempt to access the new domain in your Apache logs?  Do you see anything in your error logs?

Comment: Yes it was a 500 error. the domain was successfully sending to the correct server.I figured it out though. It was not an apache problem. It was an application problem. I forgot about the ALLOWED_HOST setting in django. I still had it set to the old domain. The error was happening at the django level.